# make grep confirm all matches

Tags: text-processing, grep

I am writing a "unit test" for a bunch of .tex files and want to check for incorrect entity names, e.g. "Data Items" instead of "DataItems".

Currently, I use `grep` to search for the incorrect versions:

```
grep -i "Data items" *.tex
```

however, the list is pretty large, also there are false positives sometimes.

I'm looking for a `grep` alternative that prompts what to do on each match. To deal with the false positives, one of the options needs to be ignore, and it needs to remember it as ignored, so it doesn't prompt about that particular instance again in the future. (Sort of like how you can tell a word processor to ignore a misspelling in the spell checker.)

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "acknowledge".

Comment: Also, if there are "false positives" then your patterns are wrong which is not `grep`s fault but yours and you need to fix your input.

Comment: edited the question, basically i would like to see every match one after another on the screen to check whether it is a valid match or a false positive

Comment: I still don't get what "acknowledge" means. Showing the matching results is exactly what grep does.

Comment: basically you need "input, processing, output"'. What do you want to do after `grep`? If you leave the Q like it is, then I'd say your answer is: `grep -i "Data items" *.tex|while read line; do echo -n "$line yes/no? "; read -u1 y; done`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're looking for some program that matches your input against some patters (like `grep`), but then also prompts you (for each match) if it should remember an exception for this one?

Comment: @derobert, correct!

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the output from scrolling of the screen using:

```
grep -i "Data items" *.tex | less
```

you would have to "acknowledge" that you want to continue reading the next bunch of output lines.